# Uncaught TypeError: n.apply is not a function - what could be the issue?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to access the parent of a node in d3 tree layout my code looks like this

Here is the function supposed to display the parent name which it accepts as parameter

```
function draw(a){
  console.log(a);

  }
```

Here is the function that calls it in the node's mouseover event, see the last line

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        var value; 
        if(d.depth == 1){value = "marker";}
        else{value = "else";}
        return value;}
    )
    .attr("r", function(d){return d.depth == 1?d.children.length:3})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d.depth>1?colors(d.parent.name):colors(d.name);})
    .style("stroke", "none")
   .on("mouseover", "draw(function(d){return d.parent.name;})");
```

However instead I get the error above. Any takers?

Comment: Quotes?? `.on("mouseover", "draw(function(d){return d.parent.name;})");`???

Comment: Didn't get why are you writing a function in side the draw(function(d){return d.parent.name;}) is there a good reason for this...

Comment: Sorry, not sure how you mean. So far in d3 its how I am able to access the current element, see first bracket where I set the circle class attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an issue with your `"mouseover"` handler. You are passing a string instead of a function, which works only in the `onmouseover` DOM element attribute (and even there it's bad practice with confusing behavior). Try instead

```
on("mouseover", function (d) {
    draw(d.parent.name);
});
```

Comment: This works, had actually tried this but I realize now that I was not terminating the line after the call to draw

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    draw(d.parent.name);
});
```

Comment: I think `d` is a datum passed as an argument to the `"mouseover"` handler, rather than a global